# Dynamic Sorting with PredicateBuilder

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, predicatebuilder

I am using `PredicateBuilder` to dynamically construct LINQ query as below.
I can easily add filter expression using`PredicateBuilder`, but I cannot find a way to add dynamic sorting using `PredicateBuilder`. For example, in code below I would like sort by `orderid` in an ascending order, but this is decided in a dynamic fashion and not known before hand.

**Question** : Is it possible to do dynamic sorting using `PredicateBuilder`, and if yes, then how would that be done? I could not find any suitable method under this class. I could only find *System.Linq.Dynamic* library suitable for dynamic sorting.

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Orders>();
predicate = predicate.And (o => o.OrderID > 10995);
var ordersFiltered = (from o in Orders select o).Where(predicate);
ordersFiltered.Dump();
```

Comment: Sorting and predicates are two different worlds.

Comment: I had to do something similar where I would not know the amount of sorts and which ones. I built expressions via reflection and chained them. I don't think you can do it via predicates in this case.

Comment: I get it now. Since dynamic linq was the goal of PredicateBuilder, I thought it would include all types of linq methods including `Orderby`. But that's not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PredicateBuilder` is there for building predicates, and you're not trying to build a predicate, so no, it won't be able to help you.